# fetch with DELETE method doesnt' work

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I made API server with DRF so if delete the data, I have to use DELETE method.

So I tried to request to server with method: 'DELETE', But it doesn't work.

[js file]

```
    fetch("http://abc/article/24",
    {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({password: '123'})
    })
```

I captured packet with Chrome Network tab, It's Request Header is OPTION.

In my code, I defined method to DELETE. But why Request Header's METHOD is OPTION?

[ADDED SCREENSHOT]

[image]

[image]

I set the response code if success, return 204, fail return 304

Comment: Please avoid using acronyms like DRF

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`

There should be no spaces between `;` and `charset`

Though clients and servers handle spaces, but it's not allowed. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt

Comment: @rash.tay Sorry. DRF = Django Rest Framework. I fixed Content-Type to your code, it still doesn't work.

Comment: `fetch("http://abc/article/24",
    {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({password: '123'})
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))`

Can you copy this snippet and let me know what's the error that you are getting? Also, can you post the screenshot of the Request/Response from your network tab? Another suggestion would be to test your API on Postman app.

Comment: @rash.tay After change your code, Method replace to DELETE but it still doesn't delete. Maybe I think I have to audit my Django server code.

Comment: Please test your API on POSTMAN or some API testing app. Send proper errors and see what happens on the server side when you send a request. Also, as Sulthan pointed out, you do not send passwords as strings.

Comment: @rash.tay I solved by Content-Type: 'application/json' and payload into http body. That works perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [SOLVED]

Solved by `Content-Type: 'application/json'` and payload into http body.

That works perfectly.